# Twilio - Can I transfer a call so that another guy from a department can get into the call?

Tags: node.js, express, twilio

Right now my system handles inbound/outbound calls, but I need to be able to transfer the call, disconnect the 1st agent from the call and wait until some other agent of the selected department takes the call.

I'm using TwiML Dial to connect the calls. I've heard of Twilio's conference library but I don't know if this is posible with conference to leave the client in a waiting state alone and some agent gets in.

here is my endpoint functions for inbound and outbound.

```
router.post('/outbound', validateTwilioRequest, async (req: express.Request, res: express.Response) => {
  const voiceResponse = new VoiceResponse();
  
  voiceResponse.dial({
    callerId: req.body.callerId
  }, req.body.To);

  res.type('text/xml');
  res.send(voiceResponse.toString());
});
```

```
router.post('/inbound', validateTwilioRequest, async (req: express.Request, res: express.Response) => {
  const clientName = req.query.clientName as string
  const voiceResponse = new VoiceResponse();
  const dial = voiceResponse.dial();
  const client = dial.client(clientName)

  client.parameter({
    name: 'callId',
    value: result
  })

  res.type('text/xml');
  res.send(voiceResponse.toString());
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Twilio Task Router than it is easy just define your worker "contact_uri" in the attributes i.e.

```
{"contact_uri":"client:yourworkernamehere"}
```

If your are using the Voice Client than make sure when generating the client access token while initializing the UI client (the softphone), that the **identity**  value matches the client name in the contact_uri of the worker attribute. e.g. **identity = 'yourworkernamehere'** , when creating the access token and `"contact_uri":"client:yourworkernamehere`" in the worker attribute.

Sure, via Twilio's conference library You can technically just keep the participant in the conference room, or better would be using Conference Hold functionality, to e.g. easily play hold music: [Conference Hold](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/06/introducing-conference-hold.html)

If it's important to you to play music while the participant waits, you could have a fake call into that conference room and use  TwiML for that fake call to play a music file (ideally 8-bit WAV for best quality).
With dialing out you mean a warm/cold transfer to a second agent? Yes, conference rooms make that easy, even more when using TaskRouter with Conference instructions: [Twilio Conference Call Concepts](https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter/contact-center-blueprint/call-control-concepts).

***If still there is any confusion let me know in the comments I will update this answer.***

Comment: what is "contact_uri"?, never seen that on Twilio Client...

Comment: Twilio Client JavaScript SDK, is to build your own Twilio softphone for your agents (maybe into your agents' web portal or standalone).
Each agent's softphone will have its individual name, e.g. "john_doe", which you can enter as the contact_uri value in the worker setup of TaskRouter, that TaskRouter will forward calls to the agent's softphone: https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/client/javascript

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a try, sounds like TaskRouter is the way to go for building a call center architecture.

Comment: Yes, it is. We have build all of our IVR/Call Center using it. Also we you can use Twilio Autopilot with it to enhance the functionality.
if my answers has cleared your queries than accept the answer. Thanks.

Comment: what's up with handling the activity of a worker with sms? does it need to be like that? and why is always changing to offline after finishing a call?

Comment: and I found that taskRouter js sdk comes with its own token capability, should I use that token instead of the Twilio Device token?

Comment: You have to use both. Twilio device token is used for making soft phone and task router token is used for taskrouter working i.e. Tasks, reservations etc

Comment: That's just an example you can modify the behavior. Like using reservation.conference I am setting a activity which keeps the agent online. You can modify the behavior as you want. Use Taskrouter's JS SDK it's much easier and flexible.